Forward some arguments in git alias but not all
If I write git config --global alias.foo '!git bar "$@", all arguments provided to git foo will be forwarded to git bar while preserving spaces within arguments. For example, git foo hi "hello there" will provide the argument hi and the argument hello there to git foo and then forward them to git bar, instead of forwarding one or three arguments.
I'd like to forward arguments in the same manner as "$@" does, except if --flag appears with a non-flag argument after (an argument not starting with -). Here, foo tries to accomplish this and then calls bar in two different ways, while bar prints arguments it receives.
$ git config --global alias.foo '!
    while [[ $# > 0 ]]; do
        if [[ $1 == --flag && "${2:0:1}" != - ]]; then
            FLAGARG=$2
            shift 2
        else
            ARGS=$([[ -z $ARGS ]] && printf "%s" "$1" || printf "%s %s" "$ARGS" "$1")
            shift; fi; done
    printf "FLAG %s\n" "$FLAGARG"
    git bar "$ARGS"
    git bar $ARGS #'

$ git config --global alias.bar '!printf "BAR "; while [[ $# > 0 ]]; do printf "<%s> " "$1" ; shift; done; echo #'

$ git foo '1 2' --flag "a b" 3 "4 5"
FLAG a b
BAR <1 2 3 4 5>
BAR <1> <2> <3> <4> <5>

It doesn't work: with "$ARGS", no spaces are argument-separating, while with $ARGS, all spaces are.
How can I forward arguments like "$@" but only with a selection of the arguments?
